# Does Hibernate's OneToOne Annotation work across multiple Join Tables

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one

I have three entities users, companies and addresses. Each user has an address and each company has an address. Each of these entities has a separate table. I want it to be impossible for an address to belong to both a user and a company.

Would a @OneToOne annotation on both the user and company join columns work?

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Address address;
    ...
}



@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Address address;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Make two classes, a residential address and a business address. Inheritance seems like a good way to do that.

Comment: My example is a simplified version. The actual example involves 10 tables all referencing a single other table. This table is very large and complex and I don't want to maintain 10 copies of the table. Also my database does not support proper table inheritance.

Comment: Sounds like inheritance to me - or some kind of join. If you have an existing database structure you should post it. Inheritance is not a database concept.